# scipy.optimize.minimize keep best solution

Tags: python, scipy, minimization

I want to optimize a function with `scipy.optimize.minimize`, that calls a function that uses at every call a new random set by `np.random.normal(m,s,N)`. Therefore at every call the function results in slightly different results. `result.success` is finally `False`.

If I track the optimization calls inside my function I see, that there is a best solution. Is it possible to keep the best found solution and get it from `scipy.otpimize.minimize`?

Comment: This informtation is not stored in the OptimizedResult object, adding a callback could help you store the inputs to your objective function but not the returns - and these cannot be reconstructed as the function is not deterministic. I only see one way: provided you can change the objective function, add logic in there to store the inputs and return each time it is called.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I did this, i.e. I use an array to store any setting and results of each call. In optimization heuristics it is quite usual to store the best found solution. So I do it manually.